# How can I use Gradle's CreateStartScripts Task

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I want to use gradle's CreateStartScripts Task to generate the script to start the application.

I use it in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
mainClass = 'UIMain';

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

task copyResources(type: Copy) {
    from 'config.ini'
    into 'build/dist'
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.default
    from configurations.default.allArtifacts.files
    into 'build/dist/libs'
}

task generateScript(type: CreateStartScripts) {
     applicationName = "Dagang"
     mainClassName = mainClass
     outputDir = "build/dist/"
     classpath = ""
}

task distribute(dependsOn: [
    build,
    copyLibs,
    copyResources,
    generateScript
    ]) <<{ 

description = 'Copies all the project libs to the distribution place.' 
}
```

However when I run the build, it runs into error like:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'dagang'.
[org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Cause: Could not find property 'CreateStartScripts' on root project 'dagang'.

Can anyone shed me some light? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either import the class (`org.gradle.api.tasks.application.CreateStartScripts`), or use the `application` plugin. The latter is generally preferable.

Answer (score 5):

`CreateStartScripts` appears to be a package-private class, hence it's invisible.

Try using the [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) instead. You can then additionally override some other properties of the built-in `startScripts` task.